# I am able to get my discord bot to GET API request from my google sheet no problem but when I try to PUT it gives 401 error

Tags: google-sheets, google-api

Having my bot API call to read and GET cell data is no problem. But I also want my bot to PUT or PATCH data into cells in my google sheet. I currently have it working with sheetdb.io but they are very limited on data per month. Where as googleAPIs is less so. But when using the google api endpoint URL I get a 401 error with the v4 call I'm using. I notice that sheetdb.io is using a v1 URL request. Is there a way to either make google api's work with PUT requests using either v1 or v4?

Because this is a discord bot I can't really use a OAuth code I think. Though, I've tried. I've also tried my API key which works for GET but not PUT requests.